# How do I turn a flex box container into a clickable link?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want all of my flexbox containers to be clickable. Not just the text and images within them. Currently, I can only click the links by clicking the images/text. I wanna be able to click the empty space of the flexbox container as well.

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apple Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apple.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>  
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home"><img class="logo" src="homelogo.png" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Store">Store</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Vision">Vision</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#AirPods">AirPods</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#TV & Home">TV & Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Entertainment">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Accessories">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a class="navtxt" href="#Support">Support</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="mba">
        <a href="#MBA">
            <a class="txt1" href="#MBA">MacBook Air 15"</a>
            <a class="txt2" href="#MBA">Impressively big. Impossibly thin.</a>
            <a class="txt3" href="#MBA">Learn more ></a>
            <a href="#MBA"><img class="mbapic" src="MBA.png" alt=""></a>
        </a>    
    </div>

    <div class="iphone14">
        <a class="itxt1" href="#14">iPhone 14</a>
        <a class="itxt2" href="#14">Wonderfull</a>
        <a class="itxt3" href="#14">Learn more ></a>
        <a class="itxt4" href="#14">Buy ></a>
        <a href="#14"><img class="i14img" src="i14.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: white;
}
nav{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 45px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 33px;
}

li .navtxt{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
li .logo{
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
}



.mba{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 45px;
    height: 685px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: top;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.mba .mbapic{
    height: 225px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.mba .txt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 500;

}

.mba .txt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.mba .txt3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.iphone14{
    display: flex;
    height: 685px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246);
    margin-top: 17px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: top;
}
.iphone14 .itxt1{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.iphone14 .itxt2{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.iphone14 .itxt3{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.iphone14 .i14img{
    width: 910px;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
.iphone14 .itxt4{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(0, 132, 255);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 12px;
    display: inline;
}

.mba .txt3:hover,.iphone14 .itxt4:hover,.iphone14 .itxt3:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

FYI I'm trying to clone the Apple Store website to practice and learn basic CSS and HTML

Comment: Can you add the html and add Stack snippet?

Comment: Just use a link as the container?

Comment: Make the mba divs into a (anchor) elements and make the existing a elements divs.

Comment: Can u send the code of the solution, I tried implementing these and they ddid not work out

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried that and it kinda messes up the flexbox. Could you just edit the new code I've posted. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You cant have an a element within an a element. Could you show the code you tried using my suggestion as I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @AHaworth, nvm it worked. I did a small syntax error. The formatting is a little off but I can fix that. tysm!!

Comment: @AHaworthi now have some weird purple underline underneath the text, what's that?

Comment: use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what is setting the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have some errors in the code. You can't use `<a>` tag inside `<a>` tag, you have additional `</div>` after `</nav>` withou pairing `<div>` and `justify-content: top;` should be `justify-content: flex-start;` :)

If you want the whole div be clickable. One solution is to do it with Javascript and make click event.

More friendly css option is make whole block `<a>` like this using flex
CSS

```
<style>
    .parentdiv {
        max-width: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .parentdiv a {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .parentdiv a img {
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="parentdiv">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
            <h2>Title of the Lorem</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor.
                Nullam sapien sem, ornare ac, nonummy non, lobortis a enim. Morbi leo
                mi, nonummy eget tristique non, rhoncus non leo. Cras elementum. Etiam
                quis quam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
                nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Maecenas sollicitudin. Praesent id
                justo in neque elementum ultrices. Vivamus luctus egestas leo. Nulla
                accumsan.
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps! :)